# XSLT logical ordering - Placing image

Tags: xml, xslt

```
CASE 1: 

<Loop type="MAIN01" name="MAIN01 Data">
            <RepeatingSegment type="MAIN01" name="MAIN REP SEG">
            <Segment type="MAIN01" name="MAIN SEG">
                <Element type="350" name="Element_Of_Main01"  param=" ">1</Element>
            </Segment>
            </RepeatingSegment>
            <Loop type="POOT" name="POOT Data">
            <RepeatingSegment type="POOT" name="POOT REP SEG">
            <Segment type="POOT" name="POOT SEG">
                <Element type="349" name="Element_Of_POOT" dt="I" param=" ">F</Element>
            </Segment>
            </RepeatingSegment>
            </Loop>
            <Loop type="SAC" name="Service, Promotion, Allowance, or Charge Information">
            <RepeatingSegment type="SAC" name="Service, Promotion, Allowance, or Charge Information - REP SEG">
            <Segment type="SAC" name="Service, Promotion, Allowance, or Charge Information">
                <Element type="248" name="Allowance or Charge Indicator" dt="I" >C</Element>
                </Segment>
            </RepeatingSegment>
            </Loop>
</Loop>             


CASE 2: 
    <Loop type="MAIN01" name="MAIN01 Data">
            <RepeatingSegment type="MAIN01" name="MAIN REP SEG">
            <Segment type="MAIN01" name="MAIN SEG">
                <Element type="350" name="Element_Of_Main01"  param=" ">1</Element>
            </Segment>
            </RepeatingSegment>
            <Loop type="POOT" name="POOT Data">
            <RepeatingSegment type="POOT" name="POOT REP SEG">
            <Segment type="POOT" name="POOT SEG">
                <Element type="349" name="Element_Of_POOT" dt="I" param=" ">F</Element>
            </Segment>
            </RepeatingSegment>
            </Loop>
</Loop>
```

Scenario, I want to insert a PICTURE before "SAC" in case 1 and before "POOT" in case 2.

Current existing logic just goes by outter loop MAIN01 , at the end of segment type = "MAIN_01" it inserts image. Which means the image appears very well before "POOT" in case 1.

```
 <xsl:if test="(ancestor::Loop[1]/@type = 'MAIN01' or ancestor::Loop[2]/@type = 'MAIN01') and (ancestor::RepeatingSegment/following-sibling::Loop or ancestor::RepeatingSegment[1]/following-sibling::RepeatingSegment[1]/@type != 'MAIN01')">
   IMAGE ADDED HERE !! 
</xsl:if>       


Expected: 
        case 1:
             MAIN01 -> POOT -> IMAGE --> SAC
        case 2: 
            MAIN01 ->IMAGE --> POOT


Current status :
        case 1:
             MAIN01 -> IMAGE --> POOT -> SAC
        case 2: 
            MAIN01 -> IMAGE --> POOT
```

Thank you in advance. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you like to have a image just before the last Loop element which is child of an Loop element.

```
<xsl:template match="Loop">
    <xsl:if test="parent::Loop
            and (
            generate-id(parent::Loop/Loop[last()]) 
            = 
            generate-id(.) )">

    -- image--
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```